# Wifi stops working - realtek r8822be - Ubuntu 19.04 - 5.0.0-21-generic - Lenovo e485

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, realtek

It appears when the computer goes to standby the Wi-Fi stops working.

Wifi works in Windows.

- `lshw -C` network indicates a wifi interface is present.
- `lsmod` indicates modules are loaded.

After researching for the large majority of the day, running the commands

```
sudo modprobe -r r8822be
sudo modprobe -r rtwpci
sudo modprobe  r8822be
sudo modprobe  rtwpci
```

resulted in restore functionality once but the second time it failed to work.

Additional troubleshooting restarting the network manager worked.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Do I need to live finicky Wi-Fi or is there something I can do to make it more reliable?  Does it appear it is an m.2 form factor is there other hardware choices that will be more reliable?

Comment: it is an usb wifi adapter? if so, there may be an adjustment to do in usb power management

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when any minor update occurs in **Ubuntu 19.04**

You need to run the following command in Ubuntu Terminal, Make sure you need to connect the ethernet cable to enable wifi in your Ubuntu 19.04

1. `$ sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms`
2. `$ git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new`
3. `$ sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new`
4. `$ sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6`

After that, you need to reboot your system. Now your Wifi Connection will be enabled in your Ubuntu 19.04 PC.

Try this method & notify us if the command worked for you successfully.

Comment: I cut an paste these commands into my terminal and ran them and rebooted my machine. It did not fix the problem and now when I run  the command                        $ sudo modprobe  rtwpci                                                                                                      my computer freezes

Answer (score 0):

> It appears it is a m.2 form factor is there other hardware choices
>   that will be more reliable?

I don't think it has anything to do with the m.2 form factor more so with the 8822be chip set itself.

In a few weeks, months or possibly years the problem will be fixed but in the meantime you can use this script to save you all the typing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: r8822be-reset
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# DESC: Reset Ethernet card after suspend, not working automatically
# DATE: July 28, 2019.

MYNAME=$0

restart_ethernet() {
   /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_ethernet(r8822be-reset) BEGIN'
   /sbin/modprobe -v -r r8822be
   /sbin/modprobe -V -r rtwpci
   /sbin/modprobe -v r8822be
   /sbin/modprobe -v rtwpci
   systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
   /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_ethernet(r8822be-reset) END'
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'
case "${1}/${2}" in
   hibernate|suspend|pre*)
      ;;
   resume|thaw|post*)
      # sleep 2;
      restart_ethernet;;
esac
```

Create the above script with:

```bash
sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/r8822be-reset
```

Make the script executable using:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/r8822be-reset
```

After resuming from suspend you can check results of script with:

```bash
journalctl -xe
```